# Trying to create an approval workflow that will update a list item with a varible from SharePoint desginer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

This should be easy, but it looks like it isn't.

I should start by saying that while this is a 2013 workflow, I am doing a 2010 workflow instead, as it has things I need in it.

I set an initiation form parameter called Syndication. which is a simple Yes / No drop down list. As you know, as soon as the parameter is set, the workflow automatically creates a variable for that value.

So I created a field in my workflow tasks list also called Syndication, which is also a Yes / No choice field. Then I went into the workflow and set up an update item in this list, chose the workflow task list, choose the Syndication field, and then choose to update with the workflow variable Syndication.

Here it is:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQZWp.png)

The issue is that when a user selects yes everything works fine, when a user selects no, however, the workflow simply gives am error occurred, and doesn't tell me what the error is.

Anything would be great.

Comment: Try to check the SharePoint Log for some more information.

C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

Comment: Would love to, but we are using a hosting service and don't have access to the servers. Ug.